# What does $conclude$ mean in this sentence?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

My friend asked me a question, but I don't know the meaning of the sentence *Conclude that $\sigma_n$ is a ring automorphism* here, does it mean *Prove that $\sigma_n$ is a ring automorphism* or *Make the following map completely so that $\sigma_n$ is a ring automorphism*? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: First option in my opinion.

Comment: Yes usually means 'come to the conclusion'. i.e show/proof

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Conclude*, in this context, is math exercise jargon for "Deduce from previous facts", i.e. use (a) to prove that $\sigma_n$ is a ring automorphism.

Answer (score 3):

The exercise gives a sketch of the direction of the proof. The word "conclude" here means you should furnish enough detail so that the result is a reasonable and understandable proof that proceeds in the indicated direction.