# A ring automorphism in cyclotomic field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

My friend asked me a question, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/745412/what-does-conclude-mean-in-this-sentence). I've thought about that for some time, but I cannot do it, I don't want to let her wait too long, can you explain it for me? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does $conclude$ mean in this sentence?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/745412/what-does-conclude-mean-in-this-sentence)

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Not duplicate :( He's asking what the question means there, and here he is asking about how to solve it here. The questions and answers to both are going to be completely disjoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) I think you can show it is a ring morphism. To show surjectivity, it suffices to check that $\zeta$ is in the image of $\varepsilon_n.$ Since $n$ is coprime to $p,$ by the Euclidean Algorithm there exist integers $k,l$ (we can take $k>0$) such that $kn + lp=1,$ and in particular $kn = 1 \pmod p.$ Then $\varepsilon_n ( X^k) = \zeta^{kn} = \zeta$ as desired.

Now for computing the kernel: We know $\Phi_p(X) = 1+ X + X^2 + \cdots + X^{p-1}.$ Now note that if I list out the elements of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/(p) :  0, 1, \ldots, p-1,$ and I multiply every term in the list by $n: 0, n, 2n, \ldots, (p-1)n,$ then the new list is simply a permutation of the original list (because multiplication by an invertible element is an automorphism of the group of units). Therefore $$\varepsilon_n (\Phi_p(X)) = 1+ \zeta^n + \zeta^{2n} + \cdots + \zeta^{(p-1)n}= 1+ \zeta + \zeta^2 + \cdots + \zeta^{p-1}=0.$$

This gives that $( \Phi_p(X) )\subseteq \ker \varepsilon_n.$ Now suppose $f(X)\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ is such that $f(\zeta^n)=0.$ Note that $\Phi_p(X)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ (it is a famous result that the coefficients are in fact integers), and that our previous work implies that it is the minimal polynomial of $\zeta^n$ as well. The minimal polynomial of $\zeta^n$ must divide any polynomial having $\zeta^n$ as a root, so $\Phi_p(X) \mid f(X)$ as polynomials in the ring $\mathbb{Q}[X].$ Now do some work to show this is actually true in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ as well (Hint: Gauss' Lemma), and conclude $\ker \varepsilon_n \subseteq ( \Phi_p (X) ).$

(b) From (a), The First Isomorphism Theorem gives $ \dfrac{\mathbb{Z}[X] }{ ( \Phi_p(X) )} \cong \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ via the map $\alpha_n: f(X) +( \Phi_p(X) ) \mapsto f(\zeta^n).$

In particular for $n=1$ we have $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}[X] }{ ( \Phi_p(X) )} \cong \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ via the map $\alpha_1: f(X) +( \Phi_p(X) ) \mapsto f(\zeta).$

So then $ \alpha_1^{-1} \circ \alpha_n : \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]\to \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ is an isomorphism which sends $f(\zeta) \mapsto f(\zeta^n),$ which is precisely the map $\sigma_n$ in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Applying the [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem) to the map $\epsilon_n$ in part (a), you get an isomorphism of $\Bbb Z[X]/(\ker(\epsilon_n))$ with $\Bbb Z[\zeta]$. Do you believe that $\Bbb Z [\zeta]\cong \Bbb Z[X]/(\Phi_p(X)) $? Combine these isomorphisms to produce the $\sigma_n$.